# React Intl FormattedRelative custom units

Tags: time, reactjs

I want to use the React Intl FormattedRelative component but I need to change to a shorter text. E.g. instead of `30 minutes ago` i need `30m ago` .

Is there option to overwrite the units or change this text.

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl), I guess you could modify the locale data to change the text `minutes` to `m`. No idea where the locale file is located though.

Comment: can you give me an example try to overwrite it in my translate object(key,value) file without success.